# Angular select ui : Fetch data from remote service

Tags: angularjs, twig, angular-ui

I try to show in a select tag my data but without success, this is what i have in my app.js

```
routeAppControllers.controller('WelcomeController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.venueName = {};
    $scope.venuesName =["elt1","elt2"]
});
}
]);
```

and in my twig file

```
<ui-select ng-model="venueName.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select a venue in the list ...">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="venueName in venuesName | propsFilter: {$select.search}">
  <div ng-bind-html="venueName | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  <small>  
    {{venueName}}
  </small>
</ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I can see the select tag with input from research, but without the elements
any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer if there is someone interested in it

```
<ui-select ng-model="venueName.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px; padding-top:10px;">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a venue in the list ...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="venueName in venuesName | propsFilter: {name: $select.search}">
                    <div ng-click='go(venueName.name)'>{{venueName.name}}</div>
                </ui-select-choices>
              </ui-select>
```